# Function template specialization for both const and non-const gsl::span argument

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Let's say I have a function that takes a `gsl::span` of an arbitrary type (templated).

```
template <class T>
void foobar(gsl::span<T> x)
{
    cout << "generic" << endl;
}
```

I'd like to create a template specialization/function overload, such that when I have a `gsl::span<float>` or `gsl::span<const float>` as argument, that function is used.

```
template <>
void foobar(gsl::span<float> x) // or gsl::span<const float>
{
    cout << "specialization" << endl;
}
```

If possible,  I would not like to write two specializations for `float` and `const float`, but catch them both with the same function. I have functions that take two or three spans, and the amount of specializations to write would grow exponentially.

I would also like to have the same kind of specializations for double, so I doubt whether `std::is_floating_point<>` would be refined enough. I've tried working with `std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, float>`, but then calls become ambiguous.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use overload and SFINAE...

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_floating_point<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
foobar(gsl::span<T> x)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
foobar(gsl::span<T> x)
{
    std::cout << "floating point specialization" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Works! Don't know what went wrong then, SFINAE can get confusing sometimes.